# Update List from other class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Application with Index and Detail view. Index show _peticiones list items. And I want to update this list from Detail view.

**Detail View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id">Id:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @id = "id", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nombre, new { @nombre = "nombre", @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="desc">Descripcion:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Desc, new { @dec = "desc", @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fecha, new { @fecha = "fecha", @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="activo">Activo:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Activo, new { @activo= "activo", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**Controller** (Update method has "id" as parameter, i can't use object like a parameter)

```
public ActionResult Detail(Peticion peticion)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var id = peticion.Id;
            _peticionService.Update(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Class PeticionService**

```
public bool Update(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var peticionOld = _peticiones.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
            if (peticionOld != null)
            {
                //How to update item list??
                return true;
            }                
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How can I update list from "PeticionService" class with just id?

Comment: Where does _peticiones come from in the Update statement? And what are you trying to update in the list. A field of Peticion I presume?

Comment: _peticiones is a list created in PeticionesService class. This is the list that I'm trying to update.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the context of the Update statement. MVC is stateless. When you post to "Update" how is _peticiones set?

Comment: I've posted an answer which I hope is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach your problem like the below.

Create a view model for your view.

```
public class PeticoneViewModel
{
   public Peticione CurrentPeticione { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a service that handles the retrieval and updates to the list source.

```
public class PeticoneService
{
        public Peticione GetPeticioneByID(int id)
        {
           //Put your implementation here.
            return new Peticione();
        }

        public bool SavePeticioneByID(int id, string newValue)
        {
            //Put your implementation here.
            return true;
        }
}
```

Then create a controller to return the Detail view and handle the update

```
public class PeticioneController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Detail(int peticonID)
        {
            var peticoneService = new PeticoneService();

            var peticoneViewModel = new PeticoneViewModel();
            peticoneViewModel.CurrentPeticione = peticoneService.GetPeticioneByID(peticonID);

            return View("Detail",peticoneViewModel);
        }

       public bool UpdatePeticone(int id, string newValue)
       {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                var peticoneService = new PeticoneService();
                return peticoneService.SavePeticioneByID(id, newValue);
            }

            return false;
        }
 }
```

Also in an ideal world your service should be injected into the controller so the controller isn't responsible for the service instantiation. But that's another issue.

Hope the above helps.